# Is using Dexter's character sprite okay, or do I have to

Tags: graphics, 2d, media

.

**Inspiration --  [Southpark game](http://www.megaderek.com/southpark/)**

(very popular if you see download count on download.com ,,, did he ask for permission ??)

I am making a 2d game based on dexter's lab theme. I've got the sprite of dexter from GSA. basically I'm not an artist, so I have to depend on already available sprites, backgrounds, sfx on websites like GameSpriteArchive etc.

But is it okay/legal to use the dexter sprite I have got ?

I wish to release it publicly too, so shall I have to make lot of changes to do that?

Is it possible to get a permission to use the sprite?? My hopes are very less in getting permission.

**Besides all that my basic plan is -**

1. Dexter's sprite from google search
2. Enemy sprites from various GBA/SNES/etc games
3. tiles/objects from these retro games
4. Background art and style from blogs and portfolios of artists behind dexter, powerpuff girls, and samurai jack

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not a lawyer.  This is not legal advice.

If you made the sprite yourself, you'd be fine.  If you got a release to use it from the creator, you'd be fine.  If it was released into the public domain, you'd be fine.

Anything else, you'd have a definate problem with.

There's also the possible problem you'd have even if you create the sprite yourself -- the likeness of the character is likely copyrighted.  However, that's not as cut-and-dried of an issue.

Unfortunately, this is one of the things you'd need to ask a real lawyer to get a firm answer on.  If it's for your own use and that of some close friends, you might be able to get away with hoping you don't get noticed (like most people who speed).  If you're planning to include this in something you distribute to the public (even more so if you sell it), you're likely to run into problems.

Comment: finally i made a game called nincompoop, it was to be finished by 30th september, so didn't give finishing touches - try here http://www.bidworkz.com/hfn/nincompoop_shaastra.zip

Answer (score 2):

probably not legal, since [Dexter's lab](http://www.toonopedia.com/dexter.htm) is published by Hanna-Barbera and was created by Genndy Tartakovsky. They would have to grant you a license - but it can't hurt to ask!

Answer (score 2):

You probably won't have to get permission if they don't notice -- it's the old "legal unless you get caught" thing.  However, I strongly reccomend that you DO get permission from the creators or not use it at all on purely ethical grounds.  After all, you wouldn't want somebody appropriating your work, right?

Comment: finally i made a game called nincompoop, it was to be finished by 30th september, so didn't give finishing touches - try here,  http://www.bidworkz.com/hfn/nincompoop_shaastra.zip